# Argument of type "dict[str, str]" cannot be assigned to parameter "data" of type "Type[empty]"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a very small serializer for the initial user registration:

```py
class UserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            "email",
            "password",
        ]

    def validate_password(self, value):
        try:
            validate_password(password=value)
        except ValidationError as e:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(list(e.messages))

        return value
```

Now I am writing tests for this serializer. These are working fine, but my IDE (vscode) shows me an typing error:

```py
class UserRegistrationSerializerTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_invalid_email(self):
        request_data = {"email": "test@test", "password": "testpwsecure"}
        serializer = UserRegistrationSerializer(data=request_data)
        self.assertFalse(serializer.is_valid())
```

The error refers to my input to the `UserRegistrationSerializer`, saying that `Argument of type "dict[str, str]" cannot be assigned to parameter "data" of type "Type[empty]"`

I am not sure what `Type[empty]` actually means and how I can satisfy the static code analysis here ... the test is working fine and as expected, I would just like to understand and learn what the IDE is complaining about.

Comment: Looks more that the code inspection tool itself is not entirely good. What if you *run* the test?

Comment: The test is running fine and returns results as expected

Comment: Well since Python is not statically typed, the code analysis tool can only guess types and do checking, these are often good (enough) but not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Django Rest Framework serializers.ModelSerializer class inherit from serializer.BaseSerializer whose __init__ method declaration is :

```
def __init__(self, instance=None, data=empty, **kwargs):
```

`empty` is a custom drf class to indicate the absence of provided data. VScode suppose that such serializer should always get an input of the same type : `Type[empty]`.

That is a strong assumption which is more suited for strongly typed language and that can be heavily criticized for python and much more for Django.